# Rotate Element on AbsolutePanel in GWT

Tags: gwt, 3d, offset

I have an `AbsolutePanel` on which the widgets are placed. Now when mouse wheel moment happens, I want to move elements one by one forward. So how to calculate that x,y,z position and place the element at the center of AbsolutePanel.

Comment: Post a link on an examle - what you want to get at the end.

Comment: on absolute panel I can have many widgets . so when I scroll the mouse the widgets will come one by one at the center of panel, also when I select the widget that widget will come at the center of absolute panel. I want to do it using x,y,z axis, z is my center.

Comment: In short I want to impelent 3D corousel  effect in java

Comment: So, how about my first answer? It's a 3D carousel. Yes it's in JavaScript, but it's has all prinсiples, explanations and calculations for any 3d carousel in 2d. You can get equations from it to made calculations in your own gwt-3d-carousel. Translation from one computing language to another is called "port". So try to port JavaScrypt 3D carousel to gwt.

Comment: but they have used some inbuilt functions which I cant use in gwt. also there z order is only used for scalling and opacity. I have ported the code but effect is not same as 3D carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try port a [JavaScript 3D carousel](http://brenelz.com/blog/creating-a-3d-carousel-from-scratch/) to GWT.

Comment: can we do it in to the gwt itself like I have list of images and when I scroll the mouse images will be ratated?

Answer (score 0):

Use [FocusPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html).

```
   A simple panel that makes its contents focusable, 
    and adds the ability to catch mouse and keyboard events.
```

No need to implement or create new classes(panels,I saw in previous question :)) which implements handlers.

Just add your childs to `focuspanel`.

Focus Panel implements all the `mouse keyword events`

FocusPanel panel = new FocusPanel(child);//Child will be your panel or widget.

Here is a nice [Roughian example](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~FocusPanel).